# How can I change the default install path by using zypper in suse 11.2?

Tags: opensuse, zypper

I want to specify the install path by using `zypper`, but I didn't find an appropriate argument when I typed the command `zypper -h`.

Can anyone help me or tell me?

**NOTE:** My distribution is OpenSuSE 11.2.

Answer (score 3):

First off, OpenSuSE 11.2 has been EOL'd so you probably want to upgrade.

However, from the man page you can change the root directory with `-R /path/to/new/root`.

This means if you do the following:

```
zypper in foo
```

And `foo` lives in `/bin/` then:

```
zypper -R /usr/local/ in foo
```

Will put `foo` in `/usr/local/bin/`